# Appendix does not appear in PDF output

Tags: appendix

Here is my code:

```tex
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Hello}
hello
\appendix
bar
\end{document}
```

When I compile this and create a PDF with command `pdflatex foo.tex && pdflatex foo.tex`, the output PDF does not contain the Appendix section at all. What is the mistake I am making in this code? The output "bar" is present in PDF but it is present in the same chapter as "Hello".

Comment: the appendix only changes the chapter counter, it doesn't do any typesetting. You will have to add a \chapter command yourself.